# Calling force:navigateToSObject from a Nested Component

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, developer-console

I am going through the documentation found here [SF Lightning Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/lightning.pdf), and during the portion where they create the Contact List view on page 36 they cover the click event using the built in force namespace action: `navigateToURL`.  No matter what I try - `$A` is null. I have debug enabled, and can see that the line immediately before that call is working fine, and receives the ID of the record for the component, but `$A` is always coming back null.

I have tried `e.force`, `e.<myNameSpace>.`, `e.c.`, etc and cant imagine that this is normal.  Everything else has been pretty smooth - but then this came along and I have spent several hours looking for anyone experiencing the same thing.  This is a last resort before I scrap both this component and the one above it and start again from scratch.

Error being thrown is:

> Uncaught error in markup://ui:click : Cannot read property 'setParams'
>   of null

I am using the exact code from the document at this time.  Any ideas to try appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code ?Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean that $A is null?

Comment: Do you have any namespace registered in your org?

Answer (score 0):

The common result for your error

> Uncaught error in markup://ui:click : Cannot read property 'setParams'
>   of null

Is that the event doesn't exist, or the definition is not present. To fix that, you'll want to use the aura:dependency tag.

```
<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:navigateToURL" type="EVENT"/>
```